# Spring Integration Java DSL with JMS listener with task executor and circuit breaker

Tags: spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

I'm relatively new to Spring Integration Java DSL . I would like to implement a pretty simple scenario which is currently done by Spring Boot application

1. Retrieve a message from JMS queue (i.e. ActiveMQ). I would like to use taskExecutor to apply configurable pool size for multithread approach
2. transform the payload to xml format . in case error at the transformer, I would like to stop the chain (do not need to continue to step 3)
3. call other channel to send xml payload to my core app via rest. In this part, I would like to apply circuitbreaker in case any error when calling my core app via rest

currently my logic is pretty straighforward

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlowWithContainer() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    Jms.container(this.jmsConnectionFactory, recordDestinationQueue)
                            .concurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers)
                            .maxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers))
                    .errorChannel("errorChannel"))
            .transform(msgTransformer, "transform")
            .channel(this.handleChannel())
            .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
            .handle(m -> {

                MessagingException me = (MessagingException) m.getPayload();
                LOGGER.debug("Message: " + me.getFailedMessage() + "\nFailed with "
                        + me.getCause().getMessage());
            })
            .get();
}
```

Can Anyone help me what best approach to apply my case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> would like to use taskExecutor to apply configurable pool size for multithread approach

That is the wrong approach; you risk message loss when handing messages to another thread.

To increase concurrency you need to increase the concurrency on the listener container instead.

You are also mixing DSL and Java configuration.

Use

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(...))
    .transform(...)
    ...
```

instead.

**EDIT**

Don't use `.get()` on the container spec there, it won't be initialized properly. The framework needs to create the bean.

Also, you still need to add concurrency to the container.

Add an `errorChannel` to the adapter to handle errors.

```java
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(Jms.container(connectionFactory, destination)
                    .concurrentConsumers(5))
                .errorChannel(someErrorChannel))
            .transform(xsltTransformer, "doTransform")
            ...
```

Comment: Hi Gary, I have modified to use messageDrivenChannelAdapter , please see my updated post above. now I need to stop the chain(do not continue to .channel(this.handleChannel()) if transformer error. any idea how to handle it?

Comment: Add an error channel to the adapter - see the edit to my answer for other changes you need.

Comment: Hi Gary, I defined corePoolSize and MaxPoolSize at the taskExecutor. just want to make sure , are those value act the same as concurrentConsumer and maxConcurrentConsumer?

Comment: No that is completely different; `concurrentConsumers` determines how many threads (consumers) will be used to consume messages; the task executor simply provides the threads for those tasks. You typically don't need to provide a task executor, unless you have requirements to set the thread name, thread factory, etc, etc.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. I've added an error channel, but it still doesn't work. whenever I got an error from the transform chain(transform xml with xsl template), it's always continue to call handleChannel. am I doing wrong? I also have requirements to control max messages to be consumed for period time and RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice to apply threshold (stops calling a failing service after threshold failures) and halfopenafter (After the end of the period to check if the system that is being requested is still failing). could you give me an example to apply that?

Comment: sorry it was an incorrect logic at my XsltTransformer bean that need fixed, now errorchannel is working

Comment: The question about the circuit breaker is unrelated; you should not ask such questions in comments; ask a new question instead.

Comment: OK thanks, I will raise the circuit breaker stuff to different question